# react cannot import images from a folder

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am not a react developer but trying my hands on it again after some time.

I am trying to import images in react. I have used other online resources to accomplish this, Some use

```
"react": "^17.0.2"


import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const ImageSlider = ({ folderName }) => {
  const [currentIndex, setCurrentIndex] = useState(0);
  const [images, setImages] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const importImages = async () => {
      try {
        const imageContext = await import("images");
        const imageKeys = Object.keys(imageContext);
        const imagePaths = imageKeys.map((key) => imageContext[key]);
        setImages(imagePaths);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching images:', error);
      }
    };

    importImages();
  }, [folderName]);

  const handlePrevClick = () => {
    setCurrentIndex((prevIndex) => (prevIndex === 0 ? images.length - 1 : prevIndex - 1));
  };

  const handleNextClick = () => {
    setCurrentIndex((prevIndex) => (prevIndex === images.length - 1 ? 0 : prevIndex + 1));
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <button onClick={handlePrevClick}>Previous</button>
        <img src={images[currentIndex]} alt={`Event ${currentIndex + 1}`} />
        <button onClick={handleNextClick}>Next</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ImageSlider;
```

I have used

```
 const imageContext = await import("images");
```

and  gotten:

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'images' in
> 'E:\Project\src\components'

```
const imageContext = await import("../images");
```

and gotten even though I have put an image folder in src and in components folder:

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../images' in
> 'E:\Project\src\components'

I have also tried to use :

```
useEffect(() => {
    // Dynamically fetch images from the specified folder
    const importImages = (context) => {
      const imageFiles = context.keys();
      const imagePaths = imageFiles.map((file) => context(file).default);
      setImages(imagePaths);
    };

    try {
      const imageContext = require.context(`../public/images/pastevents/${folderName}`, false, /\.(jpg|png|jpeg)$/);
      importImages(imageContext);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error fetching images:', error);
    }
  }, [folderName]);
```

then I get

> WARNING in ./src/components/imageSlider.js 39:27-34
> Critical dependency: require function is used in a way in which
> dependencies cannot be statically extracted

So then I searched a bit more and then used :

```
useEffect(() => {
    // Dynamically fetch images from the specified folder
    console.log("FOLDER NAME ", folderName)
    const importImages = (context) => {
      const imageFiles = context.keys();
      const imagePaths = imageFiles.map((file) => context(file).default);
      console.log("imagePaths  ", imagePaths)
      setImages(imagePaths);
    };

    try {

    const images = require.context('../images/pasevents/eventsFolder2', true);
         const imageList = images.keys().map(image => images(image));

 console.log("imageList NAME Carousel  ", imageList)

   //importImages(imageContext);

    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error fetching images:', error);
    }
  }, [folderName]);
```

Then I got :

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve
> '../images/pasevents/eventsFolder2' in 'E:\MyProject\src\components'

saem with "image" and  "image/" "/image/pasevents" but to no avail

Comment: Try too use absolute paths instead of relative

Comment: Where are the images located that you are trying to "import"? Are you just trying to "import" all the images from a specific directory? Please [edit] to provide better details what exactly you are trying to accomplish here.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to store the images in the `public` directory which would be easy in mentioning the `relative path`. `images.keys()` itself will return the array containing file paths of the specified folder.

```
useEffect(() => {
    try {
      const images = require.context("../../public/images/yourFolderName", true); // adjust the path to your image directory
      const imageFiles = images.keys();
      console.log("imagePaths: ", imageFiles);
      setImages(imageFiles);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error fetching images:", error);
    }
  }, []); //no need to get folderName if images in public
```

You can also use images from the `src` directory but change the path accordingly.

Comment: `../../public/` this is the correct relative path to the `public` directory and you can adjust the inner folder paths accordingly